# Catch both sides of a clock change PIC interrupt

Tags: pic, interrupts

I am trying to build an IR remote receiver using a PIC16F628A. To do that, I need to catch both the falling and rising edge of the external interrupt pin. From the datasheet it appears you can only receive an interrupt on one or the other edges. How would you recommend going about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to interrupt on both edges, then you can use an interrupt on change pin.  If you can't wire to one of those, I'd switch the edge of the INT interrupt early in the interrupt routine.

Comment: Does an interrupt on change pin cause an interrupt for both going high and low

Comment: Yep, that's the definition of "interrupt on change". Any change, up or down, will cause an interrupt.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's the *same* interrupt that happens for both edges, so you'll need some way to tell which edge it was, if you care.  Reading the pin first-thing usually works for most cases, but there is a short time between the trigger and when you read it that might cause problems for really fast signals.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of simple ways if you don't need anything fancy:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The selectable edge you mentioned above is only for RB0 pin, and PortB 4-7 are on change. You don't need to sample both rising and falling edge, you can only use one. Also you will need to use timer or some counter in software for the width of the pulses. I suggest you send data to pc and analyse it on your pc so you can calibrate your PIC side software better. Buy some universal IR receiver circuit they are cheap and simple to use (dont bother with photo transistors and some homemade circuits). There are lots of good tutorials on this subject maybe even some complete projects you should check them out.